# Putting in order my two packages and possibly merging them

Tags: java, classes

I am making an application which fetches tweets for a specified amount of time, then inserts those tweets in a database and when the user presses another button the top `n` words and the hashtags will be shown.

**This is my `Twitter` package:**

```
[Package]Twitter
     >[Class]TwitterTools.java
```

**This is my `Analyzing` package:**

```
[Package]Analyzing
         >[Class]WordCounting.java
```

**This is the `TwitterTools` class:**

```
public class TwitterTools {

    public static List<Status> search(Query query) {
    }

    public static void filterTweetsBasedOnCity(List<Status> tweets, final String city) {
    }

    public static Query queryMaker(final String keywords, final Date since,
            final Date until, final int count) {
    }
}
```

- `search` - returns a list of `status` based on a query
- `filterTweetsBasedOnCity` - deletes `status` from a list if they were not made in a certain city
- `queryMaker` - makes a query based on the parameters

**This is the `WordCounting` class:**

```
public class WordCounting {

    public static String getHtmlTable(final List<String[]> words, final List<String[]> hashtags) {
    }

    public static Stream<Map.Entry<String, Long>> getTopWords(final int topX, final Stream<String> words) {
    }

    public static String listToHtmlTable(List<Map.Entry<String, Long>> topEntries, final String title) {
    }
}
```

- `getHtmlTable` - returns the html table of the top `X` words
- `getTopWords` - returns a stream of the top words
- `listToHtmlTable` - converts a list to an html table

My question is how should I arrange these two packages. Should I merge them since they have only one class each? Should I split them even more by having some of the functions in another class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ideal package structure is one which indicates usage. Classes such as these which exclusively contain static methods are definitely utility classes, which I usually put in a `util` subpackage of your main application.

From what it sounds like, you don't have a main package at the moment which ideally would be your website (in reverse domain order), e.g. `com.stackexchange.codereview` so that the more specific elements are later, then on top of that you'd have the name of your application which may make it something like `com.stackexchange.codereview.tweettrends`.

This would be the core of your program, and from here you could then add on your extras.

The `Twitter` package in particular doesn't sound helpful: your entire program seems to relate to Twitter so it doesn't really convey what that part of the program does. Frankly, I'd just put all those classes under `com.stackexchange.codereview.tweettrends.util` and add in more sub-packages if you add more classes.

And generally speaking, in Java packages should be exclusively lowercase.

Comment: I agree with having a main package, but I would not use `com.stackexchange...` as that would sound like the SE team is behind it. For this user, I would suggest `com.silicontouch` or similar, if no other registered domain exists.

Comment: I already have a "util" package named `utilities` so I guess I could put these two classes in there and yes I don't have a main package so I should sort that out as well.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Yeah that was just intended as an example as he didn't mention a domain.